# How to setup SonarQube with Docker using Saltslack, and how to use it from CI

Tags: github, gradle, sonarqube, travis-ci, salt-stack

This post contins some information about how we integrated SonarQube in our workflow using Docker and Saltslack as Docker Container Configuration Management.

It also contains the setup used with Gradle in Travis-CI in order to execute analysis of code and analysis of Pull Requests on Github.

Also, if you see any improvements to this setup, please comment!

(If using Docker Compose, see https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube. Feel free to maintain this answer here or copy it to a SCM.)

Requires Docker Engine 1.9

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up a SonarQube Server using Salt**

Create this pillar file applicable for your SonarQube server:

```
  sonar-qube:
  name: sonar-qube
  port: 9000
  version: <ENTER SOME VERSION>
  version_postgresql: <ENTER SOME VERSION>
  # Using a shared disk allows you to move the SonarQube container between different servers and still keep the data.
  host_storage_path: /some/shared/disk
```

Create this `sonarqube.sls` as your Docker State file.

(It requires you to have a network created named sonarnet configured in a configuration named sonarnet-config)

```
{% set name = salt['pillar.get']('sonar-qube:name') %}
{% set port = salt['pillar.get']('sonar-qube:port') %}
{% set tag = salt['pillar.get']('sonar-qube:version') %}
{% set pg_tag = salt['pillar.get']('sonar-qube:version_postgresql') %}
{% set host_storage_path = salt['pillar.get']('sonar-qube:host_storage_path') %}

include:
  - <state file of the sonarnet-config network definition>

sonar-qube-image:
  dockerng.image_present:
    - name: sonarqube:{{tag}}

sonar-qube:
  dockerng.running:
    - name: {{name}}
    - image: sonarqube:{{tag}}
    - network_mode: sonarnet
    - port_bindings:
      - {{port}}:{{port}}
    - environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://sonar-db:5432/sonar
    - binds:
      - {{host_storage_path}}/sonarqube/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - {{host_storage_path}}/sonarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - {{host_storage_path}}/sonarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - {{host_storage_path}}/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
    - require:
      - dockerng: sonarnet-config

sonar-db:
  dockerng.running:
    - image: postgres:{{pg_tag}}
    - network_mode: sonarnet
    - port_bindings:
      - 5432:5432
    - environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    - binds:
      - {{host_storage_path}}/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
      - {{host_storage_path}}/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - require:
      - dockerng: sonarnet-config
```

Use regular salt to start your containers.

Once this SonarQube server is started, you should be able to reach the web gui of SonarQube.

**Execute automated analysis (with Gradle in Travis CI)**

These bullests will be described one by one

1. Enable Gradle plugin
2. Create users at SonarQube and Github
3. Write a bash script that executes analysis
4. Invoke bash script from Travis CI.

**1) Enable the Gradle plugin**

Enable the plugin according to documentation at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}
```

**2) Setup users in Github and Sonar**

Github requires a user with write access (soon only read access?) to the repo. Create a sonar-ci user to a team, and provide write access to the repo for the team. See this post: https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/232#issuecomment-149649126 Then create an access token for that user, the access token must grant "Full control of private repositories".

Sonar requires a user that has permission to "Execute Analysis" and "Create Projects" under Global Permissions. It also needs permissions to "BROWSE", "SEE SOURCE CODE" and "EXECUTE ANALYSIS" under Project Permissions. Generate an access token for this user.

**3) Write bash script**

This script will do a full analysis and publish the result at the SonarQube web GUI when merged to git branch `master`. This keeps track of the code evolvement over time. It will also analyze pull requests in `github` and write its findings directly as review comments.

These env variables needs to be set:

`TRAVIS_*`- set by Travis: see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

`SONAR_TOKEN` is the access token for the sonar server

`GITHUB_SONAR_TOKEN` is the access token for the sonar alaysis user on Github

sonarqube.sh:

```
SONAR_URL="https://sonar.example.com"

if [ -z "$SONAR_TOKEN" ] || [ -z "$GITHUB_SONAR_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo "Missing environemnt variable(s) for SonarQube. Make sure all environment variables are set."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ]; then

    echo "Running SonarQube analysis for pull request nr $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST..."

    ./gradlew sonarqube \
        -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL \
        -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN \
        -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST \
        -Dsonar.github.repository=$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG \
        -Dsonar.github.oauth=$GITHUB_SONAR_TOKEN \
        -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues

elif [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then

    echo "Starting publish SonarQube analyzis results to $SONAR_URL"

    ./gradlew sonarqube \
        -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL \
        -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN \
        -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish

fi
```

**4) Integrate from Travis CI**

In the `.travis.yml` add:

```
after_success:
  - ./sonarqube.sh

before_cache:
  - rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/gradle-sonarqube-plugin

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.sonar
```